# Holding the Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) is continuously setting BOOL to TRUE to my animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hi, I am currently making an attack animation when the mousebutton (0) or left click has been used for a single click only with no holding, so when I click the left click on the mouse, everything went okay but when holding it, the animation continues but then will stop on the last clip of my animation clip unless I release the left click of my mouse, which sets the bool of my attack animation to true, and everything goes to normal.**

So what should I do?

Here's my video LINK so I could describe it to you guys well, I hope someone could help me :).

https://streamable.com/wfnw5f

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    anim.SetBool("attack", true);
}

if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) )
{
    anim.SetBool("attack", false);
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with animations but is there a reason you have attack as a bool and using `SetBool` instead of having it be a trigger and using [`SetTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html)?

Comment: By the way, any relevant code should be included in the question as **text** so that the question is easier to answer and also easier to find for people with similar problems because the code is indexed and searchable. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65428495/edit) the question to include relevant code.

Comment: okaay okay i put the code

Comment: i made a video hehe so i can show you my problem guys hehehe

Comment: oh should it be setrigger?

Comment: what's the difference between them?

Comment: `SetTrigger` sets itself back to false as soon as it happens. From the documentation: "**Unlike bools which have the same true/false option, Triggers have a true option which automatically returns back to false.** A typical example might be to have a Jump option. If this option is entered during run-time the character will jump. At the end of the Jump the previous motion (perhaps a walk or run state) will be returned to."

Comment: As mentioned your bool will always stay `true` until you tell it otherwise ..so until you release the button and `GetMouseButtonUp` fires the flag will stay `true` ;)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: so that's how it is waittt, i'll try this suggestion, waittt... hmm

Comment: OH MY GOOD THANK YOUUUUUUU VERY MUCHHHHHHH! <3 IT WORKKKKKKED OMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG

Comment: THIS ISS MY FIRST QUESTION HERE AT STACKOVERFLOW A WHILE AGOO..
GOOD THING IT'S SO FAST TO BE ANSWERED THANK YOUUUU

Comment: @HuangSo I'm glad I could help! I added an answer below, so you can now [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) and that will mark this question as having an accepted answer :)

Comment: YES THANKS VERY MUCH  <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it to be set to false as soon as it is true. Luckily, triggers do exactly that.

Make <kbd>attack</kbd> a trigger instead of a bool then use [`SetTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html) instead of `SetBool`.

From the documentation:

> **Unlike bools which have the same true/false option, Triggers have a true option which automatically returns back to false.** A typical example might be to have a Jump option. If this option is entered during run-time the character will jump. At the end of the Jump the previous motion (perhaps a walk or run state) will be returned to.